# A "proof" for $0=1$ by integrating $\int \frac{dx}{x\ln x}$ by parts

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, recreational-mathematics, fake-proofs

Let's consider the indefinite integral $$\int \frac{dx}{x\ln x}.$$
We will compute it by integrating by parts:
$$\int \frac{dx}{x\ln x}=\int (\ln x)'\frac{dx}{\ln x}=1+\int \frac{dx}{x\ln x}.$$
Hence, $0=1$. The question is : is there anything wrong in these computations?

Note: I came across this example while reading a book on counterexamples in real analysis. I thought that the people here would find this funny, especially because the error is not so obvious to everyone.

Comment: Any two antiderivatives differ by only a constant. 1 is a perfect example of such a constant.

Comment: One of my favorites: $0 = (1 - 1) + (1 - 1) + (1-1) + \ldots = 1 + (-1 + 1) + (-1 + 1) + (-1 + 1) +  \ldots = 1$

Comment: Your Note suggests that you already know the answer to your question, so it's not really appropriate to post it here.

Comment: I'm sure this is a repeat... but I can't easily find it.

Comment: The error is pretty damned obvious, in my opinion.

Comment: @I.Chekhov I like this one too. Depending on how you manipulate it you can also show it equals $-1$ and $1/2$ since really it could take any value that satisfies $|S|\le 1$

Comment: Thank you guys for your input! I thought that maybe there are more like this one, but I just wanted to show people here another example. @Blue the book only said "this is wrong because we cannot reduce indefinite integrals". I basically knew that this isn't allowed, but now other users added further explanations for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is what an indefinite integral *means*. An indefinite integral $\int f(x)dx$ **is not** a *single* function; rather, it's best thought of as a *set of* functions, namely, the set $$\{F: {d\over dx}F=f\}.$$ Elements of this set are called *antiderivatives*, or *primitives*, of $f$.

This set will always contain more than one element, since adding a constant won't affect the derivative. Notation like $$\int xdx={x^2\over 2}+C$$ is shorthand for "$\int xdx$ is the set of functions of the form $x\mapsto {x^2\over 2}+C$ for some $C\in\mathbb{R}$."

So no, your observation **does not imply** that zero equals one.

---

Note that it's not always the case that two antiderivatives must always differ by a constant: if the domain of the function is "not connected," we have more options. E.g. consider the function $f:x\mapsto {1\over x}$, defined on $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, has two "pieces" which can behave very differently: the function $F$ sending $x<0$ to $\ln(\vert x\vert) + 42$ and $x>0$ to $\ln( x) -17$ is an antiderivative of $f$, even though it doesn't differ from the "usual" antiderivative $x\mapsto\ln(\vert x\vert)$ by a constant.

Comment: Noah Schweber . Could you explain what did you mean by " if the domain of the function is "not connected," we have more options" why connected here is important