# On the computation of $\int \frac{x^2-x+1}{e^x \sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

At a mathematical competition in my country the following problem was proposed:

> Compute $\displaystyle I=\int \frac{x^2-x+1}{e^x \sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

I came up with the following solution, and this is also the solution presented in my book:

\begin{align}
I
&= \int e^{-x}\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx-\int e^{-x} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx\\
&= \int e^{-x}\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx-\int e^{-x}\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)'\,dx \\
&= \int e^{-x}\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx-e^{-x}\sqrt{x^2+1}-\int e^{-x}\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx \\
&=-e^{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+C.
\end{align}

At a first glance, this seemed all right because $\left(-e^{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)'=e^{-x}\,\frac{x^2-x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

But then I thought that maybe it is not, because I am basically subtracting two antiderivatives, and as my topic from here shows ([A "proof" for $0=1$ by integrating $\int \frac{dx}{x\ln x}$ by parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275385/a-proof-for-0-1-by-integrating-int-fracdxx-ln-x-by-parts)), this is not allowed.
I went on to plug in this indefinite integral into WolframAlpha and it said that [no result could be found in terms of elementary functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x%5E2-x%2B1%29%2F%28e%5Ex%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2B1%29%29).

Yet, $(-e^{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}})'=e^{-x}\,\frac{x^2-x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ is true, so my antiderivative should be correct.
So, what I am asking is if the solution I presented is somehow correct, and if it is, then why it works, since to the best of my knowledge it shouldn't.

Comment: The last and more sharp proof for this is to differentiate: the solution is thus correct. Now, the way can see extremely non-educational or even "magical", but if I differentiate the proposed solution and I get the function in the integral then we're done

Comment: @DonAntonio thank you ! Any idea why WolframAlpha says that this cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: Don't worry too much for that: WA has plenty of little (and sometimes not so little) mistakes, typos and etc. You'll discover some of them with time. It still is an excellent tool to check stuff, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose to divide in two the function's numerator:

$$\int\frac{x^2-x+1}{e^x\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=\int\frac{x^2+1}{e^x\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx-\int\frac x{e^x\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=$$

$$=\int e^{-x}\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx-\int e^{-x}\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx\stackrel{\text{IBP of 1st integral}}=$$

$$=-e^{-x}\sqrt{x^2+1}+\int e^{-x}\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx-\int e^{-x}\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=-e^{-x}\sqrt{x^2+1}+C$$

and now perhaps it does look slightly less misterious...

And subtracting/adding two antiderivatives that are equal up to an additive constant just changes *at most* the constant...so no problem as we're interested only in primitive "functions"

Answer (score 1):

Set $-x=y,$

$$I=-\int e^y\dfrac{y^2+y+1}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}dy$$

Now $\dfrac{d(e^yf(y))}{dy}=?$

Again $\dfrac{y^2+y+1}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}=\sqrt{y^2+1}+\dfrac y{\sqrt{y^2+1}}$

Observe that $f(y)=\sqrt{y^2+1}\implies \dfrac{df}{dy}=?$

Answer (score 1):

The IBP example you mention doesn't ruin your strategy here because if you interpret an indefinite integral $\int f(x)dx$ as denoting the set of all antiderivatives of $f$ and adopt the defintion $c+S:=\{c+g|g\in S\}$, statements such as $\int\frac{dx}{x\ln x}=1+\int\frac{dx}{x\ln x}$ *are true*, so subtracting antiderivatives is allowed with that caveat.

If WA says it couldn't find an elementary result, it might just not be smart enough to find it.